# WP7 LINQ to SQL and Aggregate query

Tags: c#, linq, windows-phone-7, sum, aggregate-functions

I have added the following block of code to my WP7 app and not sure what the error means;

```
private void GetTodaysTotal()
{
    // Define the query to gather all of the to-do items.
            var boughtItemsToday = (from DBControl.MoneySpent 
                                        bought in BoughtItemDB.BoughtItems
                                        select bought.ItemAmount).Sum();

    // Execute the query and place the results into a collection.
        BoughtItemsToday = new ObservableCollection<DBControl.MoneySpent> boughtItemsToday);
}
```

The error I am getting is on the line;

```
BoughtItemsToday = new ObservableCollection<DBControl.MoneySpent> boughtItemsToday);
```

and is;

> The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection.ObservableCollection(System.Collections.Generic.List)' has some invalid arguments

I know this is something to with the LINQ query returning a decimal value, but I'm not sure how to fix it.  I am intending on binding the result into a XAML TextBlock.

Comment: I'd expect a syntax error from the missing `(`, but that's just me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, it is the fact that you are returning a decimal from your first query and then trying to cast those decimals to `DBControl.MoneySpent` objects.  You will need 2 separate queries.

Consider this.  Your first query will only get the `DBControl.MoneySpent` objects:

```
var boughtItemsToday = (from DBControl.MoneySpent 
                                        bought in BoughtItemDB.BoughtItems
                                        select bought);
```

Then, you can create your observable collection as follows:

```
var BoughtItemsToday = new ObservableCollection<DBControl.MoneySpent>(boughtItemsToday);
```

Finally, just get your sum separately:

```
var sum = boughtItemsToday.Sum(item => item.ItemAmount);
```

Comment: Steve - Thanks for the help, I see why you need to do this.  I'm not sure however how I would now bind the XAML TextBlock to the SUM value as it isn't in the observable collection?

Comment: You would simply need a property on your model to expose it.  I can't really give an example without more context of the issue at hand.